# Android application Bluetooth not working when I upgrade my device from 5.1 to 6.0

Tags: android, bluetooth, android-6.0-marshmallow

my app has searching a Bluetooth device and its work perfectly in below android 6.0 version but not search any device when i am using android 6.0 and above device.

- So please tell what I do to overcome this problem??
- Is this anther permission or code to add for android 6.0 version?

Thanks

Comment: you have to implement Runtime Permission for android 6.0.

Comment: @Chirag Savsani: Thanks you for quick answer but please tell me which permission? did u have any link??

Comment: http://inthecheesefactory.com/blog/things-you-need-to-know-about-android-m-permission-developer-edition/en and http://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html

Comment: @Chirag Savsani: yes i known but is this another way to resolve?? have u suffer from this issue??

Answer (score 0):

As mansion in [Google Docs](http://developer.android.com/about/versions/marshmallow/android-6.0-changes.html).

> Runtime Permissions
>
> This release introduces a new permissions model,
> where users can now directly manage app permissions at runtime. This
> model gives users improved visibility and control over permissions,
> while streamlining the installation and auto-update processes for app
> developers. Users can grant or revoke permissions individually for
> installed apps.
>
> On your apps that target Android 6.0 (API level 23) or higher, make
> sure to check for and request permissions at runtime. To determine if
> your app has been granted a permission, call the new
> checkSelfPermission() method. To request a permission, call the new
> requestPermissions() method. Even if your app is not targeting Android
> 6.0 (API level 23), you should test your app under the new permissions model.
>
> For details on supporting the new permissions model in your app, see
> Working with System Permissions. For tips on how to assess the impact
> on your app, see Permissions Best Practices.

So you have to request permission run-time in **Android 6.0**.

Follow [This Tutorial](http://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html) for **Request Permission Runtime**.